# How do I expand $\int e^{x^2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus

I know this cannot be finitely expanded but how can I expand it using a Taylor or a Power series? $$\int e^{x^2} \, dx=?$$

Answer (score 3):

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots$$
$$e^{x^2} = 1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2!} + \cdots$$
$$\int e^{x^2} \, dx = x+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 1!}x^3 +\frac{x^5}{5 \cdot 2!}+\cdots+C$$

Comment: This is using a power series?

Comment: All Taylor series are power series. This would be a special case of a Taylor series, expansion at $0$, also know as the Maclauren series.

Answer (score 2):

That it can't be finitely expanded depends on which building blocks you're accepting. The Gaussian is that common that it's primitive function has a name of it's own:

$$\operatorname{erf}(x) = {2\over\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$$

Since it's the antiderivate of $2e^{-x^2}/\sqrt\pi$ it's analytical with the McLaurin expansion

$$\operatorname{erf}(z) = {2z\over\sqrt\pi}\sum{(-1)^nz^{2n}\over n!(2n+1)}$$

On the other hand the antiderivate of $e^{x^2}$ is also analytical with the McLaurin expansion

$$\int e^{x^2}dx = x\sum{x^{2n}\over n!(2n+1)}$$

Now consider

$$\operatorname{erf}(ix) = 
{2ix\over\sqrt\pi}\sum{(-1)^n(ix)^{2n}\over n!(2n+1)} = 
{2ix\over\sqrt\pi}\sum{(-1)^n(-1)^n(x)^{2n}\over n!(2n+1)} = 
{2ix\over\sqrt\pi}\sum{(x)^{2n}\over n!(2n+1)}$$

And compare that of the antiderivate of $e^{x^2}$ we would have:

$$\int e^{x^2}dx = {\sqrt\pi\over2i}\operatorname{erf}(ix)$$